# X³ = 0.5 Can I find X with ln or exp?

Tags: calculus

Pow is not available in the application I have to use. Is there a way to find the equivalent of pow(0.5, 1/3) with a call to ln or exp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
x^3 &= 0.5\\
\ln\left(x^3\right) &= \ln (0.5)\\
3 \ln x &= \ln(0.5)\\
\ln x &= \frac{\ln(0.5)}3\\
x &= \exp\left(\frac{\ln(0.5)}3\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, it really is clear and solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

pow$ (0.5,\frac {1}{3})=e^{\frac13\ln (0.5)} $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $a^b = e^{\log a^b} = e^{b\log a}$

Comment: Not really a hint, but oh well. :)

Comment: @Andrew : Whatcha mean -- is it too little, or too much?

Comment: To me it looks like a complete answer, but I admit the question is rather trivial, so it might only be a hint... :) I commented, because the answer was marked as low quality, so I assumed someone thought this wasn't an answer...